# TextInput with contraint Numeric crashes the app - cn1

Tags: codenameone

I have used textInputs and everything works fine except the one with setContraints Numeric. The problem is only in older iOS devices like iphn 5

Code:

```
Label phnNoLabel = new Label("Phone No. ");
phnNoLabel.setUIID("small");
TextField phnData = new TextField();
phnData.setConstraint(TextField.NUMERIC);
```

P.S it works in android devices and iOS devices eg: in iOS 6 plus. But if I test it in older iOS devices like iOS 5 etc, the app hangs.

Comment: I suggest filing an issue on this with the specific device model and OS version. If you can get the native device logs from xcode that would help too.

Comment: ios5, os version: 10.3.3(14G60), model: MD300J/A .